# Restoring a previous build

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Sorry for the newbie question, but I am having a frustrating time with this. For some reason my app, which has been running fine, started to crash with a Bad Access error. I deleted everything I had done, still crashing. Fine, I go into Time Machine to restore the entire project to a previous saved state several days ago. Now the project is generating an error based on something I did yesterday: I created a new menu item and bound it to an Action, but the menu item and action haven't been created yet in the restored source files. Why is the project file not in sync time-wise with the source files?

Do I have to create a new project and import the files into it?

Thanks in advance,
Scott Henderson

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Xcode 4.something: Hold Option and choose Project > Clean Build Folder. Click Clean in the dialog box. Then build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode itself is caching your headers and whatnot.

Command-Option-Shift-K to clean out the build folder.

In the simulator, choose iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

If that doesn't work then continue on with:

Quit Xcode and clean out Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually. 
Remove everything there is/was a bug where Xcode will run an old version of your project.

You can also delete the stuff in /var/folders

Comment: Not seeing "Empty Caches..." under XCode menu. Using XCode version 4

Comment: In reading more about the Resume feature of OS 10.7, I deleted the file that was autoloaded and everything seems to be working fine. Except now a new blank document won't open on launch, but that's another issue ;-)